# PyMySQL selecting data in loop returns not all records

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am experiencing problems with PyMySQL data selection in loop.

1. xxx table contains one record id = 1
2. I am starting script

   ```
   import pymysql
   import time
   connection = pymysql.connect(host="127.0.0.1",
                                port=3306,
                                user="yyy",
                                passwd="yyy",
                                db="yyy",
                                charset='utf8',
                                cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

   while True:
       with connection.cursor() as cursor:
           sql = "select * from xxx"
           cursor.execute(sql)
           result = cursor.fetchall()
           print result

       time.sleep(5)

   connection.close()
   ```
3. While my script is running i open MySQLWorkbench and insert new record to xxx table, etc. id = 2
4. Problem: my script does not print new record it just prints id=1.

If i restart my script then it selects new inserted record id=2, but if then i insert another record from MySQLWorkbench it does not find it (unless i restart my script)

Can you explain how to retrieve all records from database in loop?

**Update:**

I solved problem by adding `autocommit=True` param to connection. But why I need to commit changes when I am doing select? Is it normal?

Comment: Let's learn about "Transaction Isolation Level."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But why I need to commit changes when I am doing select? Is it normal?

Yes. It's normal. You must learn transaction isolation level.

- [Transaction Isolation Level (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Repeatable_reads)
- [Transaction Isolation Level (MySQL document)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html)